# systemjs-builder - how to bundle app code and tree-shaken library code separately?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, bundling-and-minification, systemjs

I have the following structure:

**/index.html

/app/[my app files].ts

/libs/[npm copied over libraries]**

Using their example I can get a single file with just what I need, but it contains everything, including the libraries:

```
var builder = new Builder("angular/dist", "angular/dist/systemjs.config.js");

builder
    .bundle("app/app.module.js", "bundle.js")
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Build complete");
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Build error");
        console.log(err);
    });
```

But obviously my app code will change frequently, but my library code less so, so I want to use systemjs builder in Gulp to bundle my app code separately.

I read through all the examples on the [systemjs builder GitHub page](https://github.com/systemjs/builder) but am none-the-wiser.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: did you ever end up solving this? If so post the answer please!